# Xcode Source Control: how to move commits to new branch

Tags: xcode, git

I frequently get into the situation where I start developing a new feature in Xcode then realize it's going to be more complex than initially expected. At this point I've already made several commits to Main and I want to move these commits to a separate branch so that Main has none of these recent changes.

In the example below, I've added a button in commits 3 and 4 but it's proving more complex than expected and I'd like to move commits 3 and 4 to a new branch off of commit 2. How can I accomplish this with Xcode's GUI?

[image]